# Setting up VCAP (cloudfoundry) without a script

Tags: linux, cloud-foundry

I would like to setup VCAP without a script on my linux box (mostly for learning, but also for controlling which packages get installed). I want to do it for a production like system (so it's not my own linux box, but a server that I use for demo purposes)

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and I have rvm 1.10 installed). I already asked this question on cloudfoundry support (http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/21004021-single-node-vcap-setup-without-a-script-chef-etc)

Really apprecaite your input

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your post on the CF forums was updated. As mentioned there, documentation for self-install doesn't exist. Your best bet is to use the existing install scripts, read through what they're doing, and perform the process manually.

The original install script: https://raw.github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/master/setup/install

The new Chef-based install script, which will replace the original script: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/blob/master/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev_setup